# Toggle between two forms with one edit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('div#showme').css('display', 'none');
        $('#edit').click(function() {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("detected click")
          $('div#showme').toggle();
        });;
```

I have two #showme forms, and two #edit buttons, I want to show just one form at a time using Jquery, as it is currently coded, this will show both forms #showme, when one #edit is clicked. How can I fix this

Comment: Are you saying you have 2 forms with the id `showme`?

Comment: A given id should only be applied to one element. The first thing I'd do is give unique id's to each element you want a hook into.

Comment: From Wikipedia: *"An identifier is a **unique** expression in a written format either by a code, by numbers or by the combination of both to distinguish variations from one to another among a class of substances, items, or objects. For living organisms and the structural identifications of objects, identifiers could be more complicated."* (You can't have two elements with the same ID on the page.)

Comment: Thanks I've changed to a class. but How can I turn one class on, and keep another five classes off? Say each class has its own button and its dynamically generated, so I can' just hardcode it

Comment: Well if they're all forms, you could do something like ```$('button#show_form_2').click(function() { $('form').css('display','none'); $('form#form_2').css('display','block') });``` which would hide all forms then immediately show the one the user has chosen to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique, use `class` instead and select it with `$("div.showme")` and `$(".edit")`

If you want to select only one form and show it, do as I do in [this Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexBay/KdE3J/)

Comment: I can see this is the solution I need, but the select next doesn't work because this isn't a traditional parent child relationship, is there another way to specify this selection?

Comment: Try the closest() selector. Please include your html if you need help for that

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close already!  You just need to rename your "showme" divs.

An ID (as in `div#showme`) can only be used once in a page. You need to call one `showme1` and the other `showme2`, for example.

When the user clicks, do the toggle on showme1 and showme2 -- as long as they start off one being shown and the other hidden, they'll toggle between the two of them.

Comment: You should also change your edit IDs to a class too -- i.e. ```<button class="edit">Click to toggle</button>``` - then refer to it in jQuery as ```$('.edit')```

Answer (score 0):

In case both of your `showme` forms share the same ID, think twice about it. It's invalid to share the same ID with both forms. Use classes for styling and have 2 different IDs for the forms, this way you can switch between them easily.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to

- Define a class which represents the two items you want to toggle: say displayToggle
- Apply the class to those HTML elements
- Add the style `display: none` to the want you want initially hidden
- Use the jQuery `toggle` method to change the display

For example

HTML

```
<div class='displayToggle' style="display: none">First Item</div>
<div class='displayToggle'>Second Item</div>
<button id='toggle'>Toggle</button>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle').click(function() {
       $('.displayToggle').toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B2xgd/1/